# Laravel is not saving the date correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I've got the issue that my function in Laravel:

```
$case->happened_at  = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->happened_at. ' 00:00:01');
```

Is saving the day of the date not correctly, it is always turning to 1 for the day

I already checked my `$request->happened_at` with dd() and in this it is correctly shown.

maybe someone knows a solution

Comment: Share value of `request->happened_at` ?

Comment: It would probably be best to give an example of `$request->happened_at` as well as the result for running this operation

Comment: `"2015-03-30"` is the result of request->happened_at and it should be `2015-03-30 00:00:00` after the operation but the result is `2015-03-01 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to get formatted value with `toDateTimeString`

```
  $case->happened_at  = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->happened_at. ' 00:00:01')->toDateTimeString();
```